# How should I format a post_filter query to match a string inside of a string in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an array of articles in a MongoDB database that is indexed into Elasticsearch. Each article in MongoDB contains an array of author names like so: ['Michael Jordan', '...']. Each article is then indexed into Es.

In Es, I have aggregation by author working, but I also want to apply a post_filter to filter results by author. How should a post_filter query be designed to handle this?

Es Schema (can be changed):

```
{
  authors: ['Michael Jordan', 'Kobe Bryant'],
  authorsString: 'Michael Jordan;Kobe Bryant;'
}
```

This is an example query before applying the post_filter:

```
{
  ...
  aggs: {
    authors: {
      terms: {
        field: 'authorsArray.keyword',
      },
    },
  },
  post_filter: {},
}
```

If I want to find articles of which at least one of the authors is "Michael Jordan", how do I use post_filter to do so?

Comment: What is the mapping of authors ? - Can you show it please ?

Answer (score 0):

If the author field is not analyzed you can always just simply filter by term like so

```
"post_filter": { 
    "term": { "authors": "Michael Jordan" }
 }
```

Comment: I think with this answer there could be a problem where if the author string has "Michael Jackson; Alex Jordan" than this query would match that improperly. I've instead gone with the match_prase query as stated below and it works.

Comment: If it's a single string sure, but based on the authors list he provided it doesn't seem to be only a single string. Otherwise if only the authorsString field is provided then yes I agree

Answer (score 0):

The following is what worked to match the author name inside of a single string containing many author names. (Es 5.6):

```
"post_filter": { 
    "bool": { 
        "should": [{
            "match_phrase": {
                authorsString: author
            }
        }]
    }
 }
```